# Can't use relative paths in object tags in Cordova/Phonegap?

Tags: android, html, cordova, svg

I noticed that I can't use relative paths in my Cordova project when referencing them in object tags. For example, this works on the browser but not in Phonegap:

`<object id="pause" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/icons/pause.svg" class="icon clickable hidden"></object>`

However, this functions perfectly fine in both Phonegap and the browser:

`<img id="pause" src="img/icons/pause.svg">`

Using a remote path also works in Cordova, but everything falls apart when I use a local/relative one. Here's what Android spits back:

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png" align="top">
<h2>Webpage not available</h2>
<p>The webpage at <a href="file:///android_asset/www/img/logo.svg">file:///android_asset/www/img/logo.svg</a> could not be loaded because:</p>
<!-- The net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND is replaced by a localized error string -->
<p>net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND</p>
```

Unfortunately, I can't use a remote location (since that won't let me execute the onclick and onmousedown events inside the SVGs). Also, avoiding <object> tags altogether is not an option, since I need to execute and change some of the code inside the objects (like changing the fill color).

Is this a bug? If not, what can I do to get my code to work?

Answer (score 0):

A jacky workaround to this is reading the file manually using Javascript and putting the contents directly into the data attribute so that it reads `<object data="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,[FILECONTENTS]"></object>`. It's not elegant, but it works fine.